# Why its returning undefined ? What is the scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

When passing 'y' through the function argument it returns undefined but without argument it returns the valid value, But why its returning undefined when passing through argument ?

```
var y = 'Hello World';
$("button").click(function(e){
    alert(y);
    //--Returns Hello World
});

var y = 'Hello World';
$("button").click(function(e,y){
    alert(y);
    //--Returns Undefined
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becasue you are not *passing* `y` to the function. it's an *anonymous* function declaration that happens to have an *argument variable*, named `y`. you are not invoking that function.invoking of that function is done by the `click` event.

`click` event only pass one argument to the callback function, which is an  [`Event` object](http://api.jquery.com/click/). that's why the second variable of that function defaults to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to `y` variable, remove `y` from `(e,y)`:

```
var y = 'Hello World';
$("button").click(function(e){
    alert(y);
});
```

if you need information about current `event` (in your example 'click'):

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: I know what you are saying, but my question is why it is returning undefined when using y as argument ? In fact the y is already declared and the value is also assigned to it, then why it is returning undefined when passing it as argument ? Is that crazy behavior of javascript or not its something else which i should know about...

Comment: In the scope of your callback function, `y` refers to the argument. But because jquery does not pass a second parameter to the callback, the value of `y ` is undefined.